# Simple Currency values, not sure how to take input and output currency

Tags: java, currency

Write a class encapsulating the concept of coins, assuming that coins have the following attributes: a number of quarters, a number of dimes, a number of nickels, and a number of pennies. Include a constructor, the assessors and mutators, and methods toString and equals.

not sure how to  do this part:

- Also code the following methods: one returning the total amount of money in dollar notation with two significant digits after the decimal point, and others returning the money in quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies. Write a client class that accepts user input to test all the methods in your class.

  ```
  public class CoinsApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {



  Coins c = new Coins();
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter the number of Quarters: ");
  int q = scan.nextInt();

  System.out.print("Enter the number of Dimes: ");
  int d = scan.nextInt();

  System.out.print("Enter the number of nickels: ");
  int n = scan.nextInt();

  System.out.print("Enter the number of pennies: ");
  int p = scan.nextInt();

  Coins c1 = new Coins(q,d,n,p);


  System.out.println(c1);
  }
  }
  ```

what changes would I have to make with my current class?

ublic class Coins {

```
private int quarters;
private int dimes;
private int nickles;
private int pennies;

public Coins() {
    quarters = 0;
    dimes = 0;
    nickles = 0;
    pennies = 0;
}

public Coins(int quarters, int dimes, int nickles, int pennies) {
    this.quarters = quarters;
    this.dimes = dimes;
    this.nickles = nickles;
    this.pennies = pennies;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return the value of nickles
 */
public int getNickles() {
    return nickles;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param nickles 
 */
public void setNickles(int nickles) {
    this.nickles = nickles;
}

public int getPennies() {
    return pennies;
}

public void setPennies(int pennies) {
    this.pennies = pennies;
}

/**
 * Get the value of dimes
 *
 * @return the value of dimes
 */
public int getDimes() {
    return dimes;
}

/**
 * Set the value of dimes
 *
 * @param dimes new value of dimes
 */
public void setDimes(int dimes) {
    this.dimes = dimes;
}

/**
 * Get the value of quarters
 *
 * @return the value of quarters
 */
public int getQuarters() {
    return quarters;
}

/**
 * Set the value of quarters
 *
 * @param quarters new value of quarters
 */
public void setQuarters(int quarters) {
    this.quarters = quarters;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Coins{" + "quarters=" + quarters + ", dimes=" + dimes + ", nickles=" + nickles + ", pennies=" + pennies + '}';
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Coins other = (Coins) obj;
    if (this.quarters != other.quarters) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.dimes != other.dimes) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.nickles != other.nickles) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.pennies != other.pennies) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: what is the error you are getting? or if you are fuzzy on a specific concept, perhaps putting that up will help us guide you in the proper direction :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem. You can do it with polymorphism if you wanna look clever but a simple solution is much better.

Essentially you have one class (apart from your main) which I'll call `wallet`:

```
public class Wallet{
private int dimes=0;
//...etc for all denominations

//We just print the total value, essentially counting coins here
//Not familiar with american coinage; in this example a dime=5c and a
//nickel=10c
public void printDollars(){
    float total=0.0;
    total+=this.dime*5;
    total+=this.nickel*10;
    //...etc
    //Divide by 100 to get value in dollars instead of cents
    total/=100;
    //Now to format the output. Java's System.out.format works a lot
    //like C's printf.
    System.out.format("%.2f$", total);
}

}
```

Take a look at [`System.out.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) for more.

For the other part of returning the number of dimes, nickels etc. you'll just have to use the getters.

Comment: I'm concerned about the use of `float` here to store a number of dollars.  It works in this example, but it's a dangerous thing to advise someone to do - the next exercise, for example, might involve adding the money from several `Wallet` objects together; and this won't work nicely if the amounts are `float`s.  My feeling is that Stack Overflow answers should try to get these details right.

Comment: @DavidWallace You are absolutely correct. I felt that floating-point precision is good enough for this exercise but in an accounting app I'd stay away from it as well. An alternative is to get the number of cents by doing `int cents=total % 100` (disregarding any off-by-ones in there) and dollars with `total-=cents` for an integer total, and print them separately. Come to think of it that's a much better and simpler solution.